# When to use action injection and when to inject dependencies on the constructor for controllers?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

In Symfony you can direct inject a service into a controller function:

```
use App\Service\FooService;

class FooController
{
    public function one(FooService $fooService){
        $fooService->doSomething();
    }
}
```

But with the same amount of effort, you can use it in the construct:

```
class FooController
{
    public function __construct(private FooService $fooService){}

    public function two(){
        $this->fooService->doSomething();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for reasons/guides when to inject and when not to inject. What is the performance price for either one, or pro/cons,
e.g.:

- Must you **always** aim to not have a `__construct()`?
- If all methods in a class use `FooService`, do I still load them in each method, or do I now use the `__construct`?

How do I decide which solution I implement?

My current logic is "as much as you can use action injection, as this saves time initializing all the Controllers, with the downside that the method calls are a tad slower because it now has to be done there"

<sub>I think this topic is on the edge of what is allowed on SO, I'm looking for a guiding ruleset, not a review or opinion.</sub>

Comment: *I'm looking for a 'strict' ruleset*, this is the problem - who has such a strict set of rules that apply to all development.  Most will have house rules and own personal ideas.

Comment: When you inject dependencies in methods you're not differentiating behavioral abstraction from the concrete dependencies. Depend on abstractions so you're not coupled with the dependencies of your classes dependencies.

Comment: I've changed the word 'strict' of that helps.

Comment: @Martijn, at the bottom you still have a conflicting problem: _I'm looking for a guiding ruleset, not a review or opinion._ I think all of us here would just give you our opinions.

Comment: Consider posting on the [Reddit Symfony forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/).  There was an older discussion on this but I can't seem to find it.  Action injection used to save a bit of boilerplate code (as compared to constructor injection) but this kind of goes away with PHP 8's constructor promotion stuff.  I myself tend to use constructor injection just out of habit.  But it really just comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a significant performance or memory advantage in either case, the injected services are references, not new instances.

Most modern designs would not have controllers with many different methods in any case. And if many public methods of the same class had very different dependencies, maybe all these methods did not belong in the same class to begin with?

In the end, these design differences are an stylistic choice. Nowadays, constructor injection tends to be preferred (around me, at least), because since the dependencies are what the class needs to have to be in a **valid stated** to work, passing them at instantiation time seems more logical to many.

There is nothing inherently wrong in passing this as method parameters in many cases (as in having any other type of `callable`s as a parameter), but what I believe is best is **to think of controller actions as any other method**:

- how does the method reads more clearly?
- would a method consumer need to know the class dependencies, and change the dependencies at call-time, or is that beyond the responsibilities of the consumer?